# How to reduce an excel table to non empty rows with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I have the following code which reduces the table to the header + 1 row.
This is great if the table is empty, but I also want to use it if there is data in the table.
In this case I would want to reduce the table to the row of the last data entry.
Column A will always have data in it, if there is data in the row.
There will be no empty rows between the top and the bottom of the list of used rows.
If anyone can show me how to amend the code to that effect i would really appreciate it.
Many thanks for any help

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim lstObj As ListObject

    Set lstObj = Sheets("Sheet6").ListObjects("TSheet6")

    With lstObj

        'Following line resizes the table to headers Plus 1 row
        .Resize lstObj.Range.Resize(2, .Range.Columns.Count)

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `.Resize lstObj.Range.Resize(2, .Range.Columns.Count)` to `.Resize lstObj.Range.Resize(.Range.Columns(1).Rows.Count, .Range.Columns.Count)`

Comment: Also it will be better if you can add a screenshot of the Table that you want to reduce in Size.

Comment: Would the `Filter` not work?

Comment: No, sorry Mikku, that doesnt do anything

Comment: Zac, i dont know what you mean.